# clone vagrant box into a fresh one

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, packer

I built a vagrant box via using packer. It generates a `.box` file and I was able to use vagrant to bring it up. Now I would like to build a cluster of, say, 2 machines. So I'd like a new machine from ideally the same `.box` file. I google a bit and found that I could use `vagrant package` to create a new box. So I tried that and indeed the re-packaged box has a different hard drive, which is good. But it still has the same MAC address as the original one. I know I can manually change the MAC address from within Virtualbox but that's not ideal.

Is there a way to create a completely **fresh** new box out of an existing one?